# check whether a cell/ column in gridView is read only or not using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using VS 2005, C#.net , ASP.net.
I have a web application .
How to check whether a cell/ column in gridView is read only or not using Jquery

Thanks in advance

George n t

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo using table.

```
$("td[readonly]").click(function(){
alert("I am readonly")
 });
```

Its is the working fiddler-  http://jsfiddle.net/aWbTE/33/

Comment: The following is my requirement.arrow key should navigate only through the  editable columns in gridview.Arrow keys shouldn't navigate through the read only columns in grid.